# How a fetch() works?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have a react app and I set it's proxy to 'http://localhost:4000/api' and with this I fetch like below

```
fetch('/posts/dp/upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
  })
```

which works fine

but when I change my proxy to https://social-firegram.herokuapp.com/api, it still sets the proxy to 'http://localhost:4000/api'

how can I fix this issue fetch my data from https://social-firegram.herokuapp.com/api ?

this is my proxy

```
"name": "fb-clone-frontend",
"version": "0.1.0",
"proxy": "https://social-firegram.herokuapp.com/api",
"private": true,
```

Comment: How are you setting the proxy exactly…?

Comment: You may also need [a procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile).

Comment: What error do you get when you use `fetch("https://social-firegram.herokuapp.com/api")` ?

Comment: You literally left out the one important thing there and that is how you set the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Heroku can be a pain, so I've looked at one of my projects and I'm going to list the things I had to do.

Don't change the proxy like you're currently doing.

Here's the line from my `package.json`. It always stays the same.

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:4000",
```

and the line from my express app:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
```

In short - unless you pass in a environment variable - the port will be automatically set to 4000 which is your proxy.

If you don't have one set up a [`procfile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile). Here's mine.

```
web: node src/server.js -port 8000
```

You can see that it uses port 8000. Your server will be able to differentiate that from your proxy.

Finally update your `scripts` section of your `package.json` if you haven't already done so to include the [postbuild step](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process).

```
"heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
```

Answer (score 0):

Still keep fetch logic.

```
  fetch('/posts/dp/upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
  })
```

Just update `proxy` from "localhost" to new proxy

```
"proxy": "https://social-firegram.herokuapp.com/api",
```

Comment: Yes. Keep it logic instead `fetch('https://social-firegram.herokuapp.com/api/posts/dp/upload'` like he post before